# Make SSH/gpg-agent not ask for passphrase for key it's not going to use

Tags: linux, ssh, gnupg

I have two SSH keys. `id_rsa` is my normal one with a passphrase, and `id_lynx` has no passphrase because I want it to be usable in a cron job (the user it logs in as is fairly restricted, don't worry about that), specifically git synchronization. For these background git pushes and pulls, I have set up an SSH host entry in my `~/.ssh/config` that specifies `id_lynx` as the `IdentityFile`. Also, Xfce starts up `gpg-agent` with ssh-agent support.

Now when I try to connect via SSH using this host, which only cares about `id_lynx`, I get a pinentry popup from `gpg-agent` asking me for the passphrase for `id_rsa`. If I hit the cancel button, the connection proceeds fine (as it should), but this is obviously not a good final solution, especially for use in a cron job.

If I kill `gpg-agent`, everything works as expected, but I like having the graphical ssh-agent implementation, except for this one issue.

So, how can I prevent SSH and gpg-agent from trying to get the passphrase for a key it's not going to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ssh -v (or -vvv) and watch the order the ssh keys are tried. If id_rsa comes first something went wrong with your ssh_config.

Try using ssh -i /path/to/id_lynx If this works check your ssh_config for

IdentityFile <- should be a fully specified path,

IdentitiesOnly yes

man 5 ssh_config says:

```
   IdentitiesOnly
         Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity
         files configured in the ssh_config files, even if ssh-agent(1) or
         a PKCS11Provider offers more identities.  The argument to this
         keyword must be ``yes'' or ``no''.  This option is intended for
         situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities.  The
         default is ``no''.
```

That should do the trick. If not, investigate the output of ssh -vvv wheter your ssh_config is used at all.

Comment: Putting `IdentitiesOnly yes` in the host config block seems to have done the trick. SSH is no longer trying to offer id_rsa in the -vv output. Another problem caused by failing to read the directions closely enough...